# When to use a UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

If I want to implement a view as below, **should I use a UITableView or simply use UIViews, UILabels... and keep autolayouting them?**

I'm a little confused when it's the best time to use UITableView. Just for populating a list of single-lined items (with small images and/or accessories)?

I didn't find really good tutorials about **how to make UITableView as customized as below**. Is it a good choice? Any advice on that?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Table views are great when you have a single column of rows with repeated elements. Each row can be simple or complex (they are most certainly not limited to single-line items!).

Collection views are great when you want more control over layout; a multi-column grid, or even a circular layout.

When the elements are stacked in a column but are not repeating, you can still use a table view, but since iOS 9 it's simpler to use a UIStackView.

In the stack view scenario, I find it convenient to break the layout into sections (e.g. photo, description, cooking instructions, ingredients, nutrition, ... whatever applies to your app). Each section is built separately - either in code or in a XIB. Without one massive XIB, future changes and insertions are simplified. Each section is loaded and added to a stack view which itself is the child of a scroll view (which is a child of the view controller's view).  Since the sections are non-repeated, you can set your view controller to be the "File's Owner" and link up views to outlets, which makes data population straightforward.

In your screenshot I can't tell if there is any scrollable area or if that's a fixed content. If it's fixed content, I would just lay that out in IB with autolayout. I'd be very tempted to use two stack views (watch the UIStackView intro WWDC video from 2015) for those two columns, though since I've never had much luck with stack views in IB, I'd likely fall to using basic auto layout.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the right place to use a UITableView. UITableViews are for a list of single-line items as you mentioned. Although it may seem tedious, your best bet is to use labels, views and buttons to create the interface.

You could also look into a collection view. I don't think this suits your needs, but its worth knowing about: [UICollectionView Tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview).

Comment: Using a `UIStackView` will make things much easier too when you're manually laying things out.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I advise you to use just **UIViews**, **UILabels** and **UIImages**, all this inside of a scrollView.

This will give to you the scroll that UITableView has and will be easier to handle with data.

Or, you can also use UICollectionView, what can result in the same.

Explaining just a little bit more about **UITableView** vs **UICollectionView**

Is more common that people uses [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview) to create lot's of different views displayed in a grid. (This can be created using UITableView, but with too much more complexity)

In the other hand, is more common that people uses UITableView to displays a list of items in a single column. [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview)

Buut, as I said, if you want to display some informations as a grid and other as a list, you can also mix both.

So in this case, you should use UICollectionView inside of UITableView, and to do that, you need to remember that UITableView can have lots of different cells types and sections.

An example of code is:

```
-(UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    id item = [self getItem:indexPath];

    id cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[[self getCellClassForItem:item] description]];
    [self setDataToCell:cell withData:item];

    return cell;
}
```

this methods (`-(Class) getCellClassForItem:(id)item;` and `-(void)setDataToCell:(id)cell withData:(id)item;` ) are important to inform the tableview what should they do with those kind of cells, so:

```
-(Class) getCellClassForItem:(id)item {
    if ([item isKindOfClass:[YOUR_CELL_CLASS_1_MODEL class]]) {
        return [YOUR_CELL_CLASS_1 class];
    } else if ([item isKindOfClass:[YOUR_CELL_CLASS_2_MODEL class]]) {
        return [YOUR_CELL_CLASS_2 class];
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}


-(void)setDataToCell:(id)cell withData:(id)item {
    if ([cell isKindOfClass:[YOUR_CELL_CLASS_1 class]]) {
        //populate your cell
    } else if ([cell isKindOfClass:[YOUR_CELL_CLASS_2 class]]) {
        //populate your cell
    } 
}
```

and do not forget to implement the mandatory methods like:

```
-(NSArray *)getCellsClasses {
    return @[YOUR_CELL_CLASS_1.class, YOUR_CELL_CLASS_2.class];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use UICollection view instead.As the 2 views of yours are horizontally placed.If you have to add more of them you can directly add collection view cells.
Customize the cell and use autolayouts in the same.
If the features used to describe may vary in numbers you can then use table view for the same.